# Fixing the format of select rows in date column in a dataset

Tags: sql-server, date, format

I'm working with a dataset about bakery sales.

I noticed that the date column's formatting is inconsistent.

For example, these are some of the dates as appearing on the dataset

```
2016-09-11
2016-09-12
2016-10-11
2016-10-12
2016-10-30
2016-10-31
2016-11-11
2016-11-12
2016-11-13
```

From what I've observed, the first 12 days of each month are formatted in yyyy/dd/mm, then it flips to yyyy/mm/dd. The result is that I have some false dates and some missing dates. The data should only contain dates 10/31/2016 to 04/09/2017. Is there an easy fix in SQL that I can use or is this a problem that has to be fixed in the data itself? I am using SQL Server.

Comment: You can use a CASE expression based on DAY(column) <= 12 to then convert to date using the appropriate style. You could also define that as a computed column (or just fix the table itself).

Comment: Good gravy, the page says `the time period from 26-01-11 to 27-12-03` ... who on earth expresses dates in this way, never mind that even if they meant 2016 (not 26) and 2017 (not 27), I'm not sure how that possibly maps to 20161013 -> 20170409

Comment: Please don't ask us to access data via potentially dodgy external links, put your sample data as formatted text into the question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yeah I have no idea what that time period is, I got my timeframe from looking at the dates in the dataset.

Comment: And if the formatting is inconsistent then you must be storing the dates as strings instead of dates - which is going to cause you plenty of future issues - use the correct datatype and avoid all these issues.

Comment: @DaleK It appears to be an external dataset not under control of OP

Comment: @SMor I initially was thinking case was the way to go, but for example, how could i convert 2016-09-11 (yydm) to 2016-11-09 (yymd) when the data thinks it is already in yymd format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, answering just in case in the future someone has similar issue. Thanks to @SMor for his suggestion with the case expression.

```sql
SELECT    DISTINCT date, 
  CASE 
    WHEN  day(date) <= 12 
    THEN  datefromparts(datepart(year, date), day(date), datepart(month, date)) 
    ELSE  datefromparts(datepart(year, date), datepart(month, date), day(date))  
  END     AS revised_date
FROM      bakery_sales
ORDER BY  revised_date
```

Comment: Please mark as answer so this sucker drops off the list? Thank you.